# валидация checkbox и text

Tags: javascript, валидация, checkbox

Я делаю валидацию для регистрации пользователей. На странице присутствуют как обычные input, так и input с типом checkbox. Валидацию для полей ввода я сделал,  а вот с checkbox'ом возникли проблемы. весь интернет облазил, но ничего путного так и не нашел. буду благодарен за помощь.

```
function validation(form) {

    function removeError(input) {
        const parent = input.parentNode;

        if (parent.classList.contains('error')) {
            parent.querySelector('.error-label').remove();
            parent.classList.remove('error');
        }
    }

    function createError(input, text) {
        const parent = input.parentNode;
        const errorLabel = document.createElement('label');

        errorLabel.classList.add('error-label')
        errorLabel.textContent = text;

        parent.classList.add('error');

        parent.append(errorLabel);
    }

    let result = true;

    const allInputs = form.querySelectorAll('input');
    const checkbox = document.getElementById('politics');

    for (const input of allInputs) {

        removeError(input);

        
        if (input.value == "") {
            console.log("Ошибка");
            createError(input, "Поле не заполнено");
            return false;
        }
        

        
    }


    return result;
}

document.getElementById("add-form").addEventListener('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if (validation(this) == true) {
        alert('Форма проверена');
    }
})
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос разметку html и описание, как должна работать проверка чекбоксов

Comment: [Input Checkbox checked Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp), [input type="checkbox"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox). Но для тривиальных случаев я бы использовал [data-атрибуты](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) для проверки формы. Также посмотрите в сторону нативной [валидации форм на стороне клиента](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation).